# WCF proxy client generated with wsdl not matching for ServiceContract, XmlSerializerFormat attributes

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I am developing WCF services in .net 3.5 framework and hosting them in IIS 5.1 windows xp sp3 with **basicHttpBiding**.
 Services consuming client developed in .net 2.0 framework. For this I generated proxy client using WSDL.EXE. This tool generates proxy class without any problem, but the problem it adds for every property adds extra property **"[property]Specified"**, but that work fine without any problem, only need to specify **"specified = true"** when assigning value to any property
 To remove this extra property I added **XmlSerializerFormat** attribe along with **ServiceContract** attribute. WSDL.EXE generates the class without extra property, **but it excludes some class which are included previously**.

**Is there any properties that I need to set to generate the excluded classes?**
Note: All contract classes are attributed with **DataContract** and properties with **DataMemeber**.


nRk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XmlSerializer uses [XmlIncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) instead of `KnownTypeAttribute` to discover child types that are not included in operation contracts. So you might try adding them to the base class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ChildClass1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ChildClass2))]
public class BaseClass {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard WCF DataContractSerializer will serialize everything marked with `[DataMember]` - regardless of the .NET visibility (public/protected/private/internal).

When you switch to the XmlSerializerFormat, the behavior changes - now the XmlSerializer will serialize everything that has a `public` visibility, and does not have a `[XmlIgnore]` marked on it.

I would assume some of your classes and members are not marked with `public` and thus don't get serialized anymore. Also the XmlSerializer requires classes to have an explicit, parameter-less constructor which will be used in deserialization - do all your classes have that? And of course, that constructor also needs to be `public`.

Comment: Thanks Marc, As you specified  all properties are having public and having default constructor. The problem is comming, where I need to return to one method is base class, which is inherited by 8 child classes, but I am getting in proxy only 4 classes. All inherited classes are haivng public/default  constructor and all properties are public. All classes decorated with DataContract and properties with DataMember attrigute.

Comment: The DataContract/DataMember attributes don't matter here if you're using the XmlSerializer. Are all your 8 child classes defined somewhere in a `[KnownType]` attribute on an operation contract? I would think only those that are mentioned specifically either as a parameter in an operation, or by means of the known-type attribute, will be serialized

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Sorry, I forgot to mention that, in the base class I added attribute [KnownType(typeof(childclass))], I added   8 attributes for each child class.